# SignalR Multiple Hub Connection .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I have 2 Hub classes,

**SystemNotificationHub.cs**

```
public class SystemNotificationHub : Hub { }
```

**QuotationChatHub.cs**

```
public class QuotationChatHub: Hub { }
```

`SystemNotificationHub` is defined in `_Layout.cshtml` so user is connected to hub continously,
and when user enters to `QuotationChat.cshtml` page, I want also same user to connect the `QuotationChatHub`, so in a simple manner I'd like the user to connect multiple hubs at the same time.

**I cannot let user to connect more than 1 hub at the same time. How can I achive this?**

**StartUp endPoint Configurations**

`endpoints.MapHub<SystemNotificationHub>("/systemNotificationHub");`

`endpoints.MapHub<QuotationHub>("/quotationHub");`

**quotationChat.js**

```
$(function () {
    if (connection === null) {
        connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/quotationHub")
            .build();

        connection.start().then(function () {
            document.getElementById('sendButton').onclick = function () {
                connection.invoke("BroadcastFromClient")
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        return console.error(err.toString());
                    });
            };
        });
    }
});
```

**notification.js**

```
$(function () {
    if (connection === null) {
        connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/systemNotificationHub")
            .build();

        connection.on("Notify", function (response) {

        });

        connection.on("HubError", function (response) {
            alert(response.error);
        });

        connection.start().then(function () {
            connection.invoke("NotificationMethod")
                .catch(function (err) {
                    return console.error(err.toString());
                });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay - so whats you're quesiton exactly? - try and make it a singular question with an actual quesiton mark so we clearly understand what you need

Comment: you only described your situation here. please add an actual question

Comment: I've edited the question, simply I cannot let user to connect more than 1 Hub at the same time. Only 1 Hub which is the first one that user connects is working, quotationHub is not working when user enters that specific page.

Comment: Actually as I see, before the edit, he just forgot a question mark, and the other hand statements are okay where he says that he cannot connects users to 2 hubs at the same time.

Comment: so basically if i understand you correctly you want the ability to drop a connection when one is made on a different hub? 
if so just fire an event to a hub manager that will disconnect the client from other hubs...

Comment: No, I want to connect both of the hubs, now, because of the SystemNotificationHub connection, it seems I cannot open another connection to QuotationChatHub @Liran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this issue is related with your if condition in your codes.

You have checked connection is null or not before creating the connection builder. But all two js use the same connection model.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could try to create a new connection for systemNotificationHub for example connection1 and then your code will work well.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

quotationChat.js not changed.

notification.js:

```
//Define a new connection1 as the new js object as connection
$(function () {
    if (connection1 === null) {
        connection1 = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/systemNotificationHub")
            .build();

        connection1.on("Notify", function (response) {

        });

        connection1.on("HubError", function (response) {
            alert(response.error);
        });

        connection1.start().then(function () {
            connection.invoke("NotificationMethod")
                .catch(function (err) {
                    return console.error(err.toString());
                });
        });
    }
});
```