# How to connect multiple hubs in SignalR and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I tried following code. I have chathub and msghub, in the client code I don't know how to configure 2 hubs in asp.net core.

// Client code

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("https://localhost:44364/chathub" , {accessTokenFactory: () => this.loginToken `
}).build();
```

```
connection.start()
          .then(() => console.log('connected!'))
connection.invoke('SendMessage', message);
messageBox.value = '';
});
```

// start up configuration

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
    endpoints.MapHub<MsgHub>("/msghub");
});
```

// hub class

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
}
```

```
public class MsgHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use one hub and multiple hubs are the same in js code, just note you need create a new connection if you use another hub. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64536810/signalr-multiple-hub-connection-net-core).